# Container overrides default style

Tags: wpf, containers, styles

I have a 3rd party control in which i have added a toolbar in it's header container. The toolbar and child items show normally but the selection styling (highlighting of the child items) doesn't trigger. Somehow the header container overrides this. Is there anything i could do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check why exactly this is happening first. Assuming that something is being overwritten is a first step, but you'd have to find out exactly what it is.

I suggest you try [Snoop](http://snoop.codeplex.com) - It allows you to see what is the exact Visual Tree of your application - If you are correct then you will see which property is overridden by which control.